# How to test for the string '...loading' in React component that uses styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, styled-components

**How do you write jest enzyme assertions for styled components?**

Normally I set up tests like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
// test-setup.js
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import Post from '../components/Post';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import HeaderDefaultPropsInit from './default-props/Header.defaultProps';
//import localStorage from './../../setUpTests';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('The header before all of the articles have been read', () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    const defaultProps = {
      ...HeaderDefaultPropsInit,
      fetchPost: jest.fn(),
      history: {
        push: jest.fn(),
      },

    };
    wrapper = shallow(<Header  {...defaultProps} />);
  });
```

The output of wrapper will look almost like a normal html block.
Normally i write assertions using `wrapper.find('some-element')` like this:

```
it('renders the image correctly', () => {
     expect(wrapper.find('.image').hasClass('image')).toBe(true);
   });
```

but this is for testing the output of jsx rendered by enzyme and the output is easy to traverse because you can just use jQuery type syntax because it comes out just like html.

**However:**

When i used styled components the result of 
console.log(wrapper.debug())
is this:

```
  <styled.div>
        <styled.div color={[undefined]}>
          <styled.span>
            ...loading
          </styled.span>
          <br />
          <strong className="h4">
            <styled.span />
          </strong>
        </styled.div>
      </styled.div>
```

**Shock horror theres no normal html elements to write normal assertions for!**

How on earth do you write an assertion for:

```
<styled.div>
```

instead of

```
<div class="some-class">
```

There is nothing to differentiate one element from an other

```
expect(wrapper.find('styled.div').contains('..loading')).toBe(true);
```

could refer to any styled.div

I just want to test if it contains the '..loading' message.
i must be missing something obvious - how does everyone else do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is to give the styled component a display name after you create it.

```
const CalloutWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 450px;
`;


CalloutWrapper.displayName = 'CalloutWrapper';
```

Then when you render it with `console.log(wrapper.debug())`

it looks like this:

```
 <CalloutWrapper>
   ...loading
 </CalloutWrapper>
```

and you can do assertions almost as normal

```
 it('it renders  the loading message', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('CalloutWrapper').html()).toContain('...loading');
  });
```

see here https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/896